# IWizard extension is not found by ItemTemplate installed by VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wizard, itemtemplate, vsix, vspackage

Has anything changed in VS2013 in regard to the loading of DLLs within a VSIX that has a ItemTemplate with an IWizard extension.

I know this works with VS2012. 
My sln has a WizardExtension Class Library, an ItemTemplate, in which the .vstemplates refers to the Class Library containing the Wizard, and a VSIX.

In the Exp Instance, when trying to add a New Item to the debugging project, VS just provides the error message that the itemtemplate is trying to load the component.

As I said, I know that this works fine in VS2012. The class library is correct, as I can sign and load in the GAC and it is fine. But I don't want to load in GAC but keep it exclusively as a VSIX. I tried a .pkgdef to provide bindings, but that goes not solve issue.